# onResume getting called many times even after it comes to foreground. Why?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

***I want to call onResume only when my app goes in background. I have two Activities A & B. While switching from Activity B to A i need to prevent the onPause() & onResume() call. If my app is no more on the screen or it goes to background state then only onResume & onPause should be called. Below is my code snippet. please help!***

```
    BiometricManager mBiometricManager;
    UserSession userSession;
    boolean shouldExecuteOnFirstTime;
    boolean isPaused = true;
    private Dialog dialog;
    private ActivityNewMainBinding binding;
    SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor;

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        isPaused = pm.isScreenOn();

      }


    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
       /* */
        if(isPaused)
        {
        if (shouldExecuteOnFirstTime) {
            if (userSession.isLoggedInV2()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocksWithoutKeystoreActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                mBiometricManager = new BiometricManager.BiometricBuilder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setTitle(getString(R.string.biometric_title))
                    .setDescription(getString(R.string.biometric_description))
                    .setNegativeButtonText(getString(R.string.biometric_negative_button_text))
                    .build();
                //start authentication
                mBiometricManager.authenticate(new BiometricCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSdkVersionNotSupported() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
   getString(R.string.biometric_error_sdk_not_supported), 
  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBiometricAuthenticationNotSupported() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.biometric_error_hardware_not_supported), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBiometricAuthenticationNotAvailable() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.biometric_error_fingerprint_not_available), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBiometricAuthenticationPermissionNotGranted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBiometricAuthenticationInternalError(String error) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationFailed() {

                    }

                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationCancelled() {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocksWithoutKeystoreActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.biometric_cancelled), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mBiometricManager.cancelAuthentication();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationSuccessful() {
                        try {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainDashBoardActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationHelp(int helpCode, CharSequence helpString) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode, CharSequence errString) {

                    }
                });

            }
        } else {
            shouldExecuteOnFirstTime = true;
        }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior, I refer you to the android [activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) & [fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) lifecycles:

[image]

It is normal for an activity to call onPause() when switching between activities. You may be looking instead for onStop() or onDestroy() methods as a better fit although I suspect that your underlying design may be flawed (a topic for a separate question). I suggest you re-phrase your question to instead tell us what kind of behaviour you are trying to achieve and include the code that you are currently using.

If you are instead switching fragments in and out of an Activity you should refer to the Fragment lifecycle which is interconnected with the Activity to which it is inflated:

[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/images/fragment_lifecycle.png)

In this instance, you may find that onPause() for an fragment is called even when the underlying Activity is not changed. This, again, is normal behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

onResume is called every time your activity gains focus,
maybe you want to move your code to onStart which only gets called once when app gets on foreground

Comment: This is not true. If you have 2 activities and move from `A` to `B`, the following lifecycle methods of `A` will be called: `onPause(), onStop()`. When returning from `B` to `A` (by pressing BACK key), the following methods of `A` will be called: `onRestart(), onStart(), onResume()`.